# Plane wave propagation constants being equal across all components

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, plane-wave

Starting from the wave equation for electric field in free-space,

$$ \nabla^{2}\boldsymbol{E}+k^{2}_{0}\boldsymbol{E}=0, $$
where $k_{0}$ is the free-space wavenumber, we usually proceed in deriving the plane wave general solution by writing this wave equation for each component of $E$, such as

$$ \nabla^{2}E_{j}+k^{2}_{0}E_{j}=0, $$
with index $j=x,y,z$, then by using separation of variables, say: $E_{x}(x,y,z)=f(x)g(y)h(z)$, then after some simplifications we reduce each PDE into 3 independent ODEs with 3 constants, such as:

$$ \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}+k_{x}^{2}f=0\ \ ; \ \ \frac{d^{2}g}{dy^{2}}+k_{y}^{2}g=0\ \ ; \ \ \frac{d^{2}h}{dz^{2}}+k_{z}^{2}h=0\ \ ; \ \text{with}\ \ \ k_{x}^{2}+k_{y}^{2}+k_{z}^{2}=k_{0}^{2}.$$

This gives solutions of the form:

$$E_{x}(x,y,z)=Ae^{\pm i(k_{x}x+k_{y}y+k_{z}z)},$$

and similarly,

$$E_{y}(x,y,z)=Be^{\pm i(k_{x}x+k_{y}y+k_{z}z)},$$
$$E_{z}(x,y,z)=Ce^{\pm i(k_{x}x+k_{y}y+k_{z}z)}.$$

The question here is about the reason behind assuming that all the constants ($k_{x},k_{y},k_{z})$ are identical for all the three field components, given that this was not actually necessary during derivation?

Some textbooks (e.g. [Pozar](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microwave-Engineering-David-M-Pozar/dp/0470631554/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1525129526&sr=8-2&keywords=pozar%20microwave)'s book, or [Collin](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Foundations-Microwave-Engineering-Electromagnetic-Theory/dp/0780360311/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1525129582&sr=1-1&keywords=collin%20microwave)'s classical text) give an abridged explanation, referring to the necessity to satisfy Maxwell's divergence equation $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{E}=0$ everywhere, which eventually requires us to put the same propagation constants ($k_{x},k_{y},k_{z})$ across all E components. However, this is still not very clearly worked out for me, and it would help if it could be explained more explicitly.

Comment: There is a requirement that the propagation vector and the polarization vectors are mutually orthogonal. If you give the different components different propagation vectors then they will act as different plane waves. This is not a problem, provided that you can maintain the orthogonality requirement.

Comment: @flippiefanus Yes, but the orthogonality requirement actually comes afterwards: when we continue with $E_{x}=Ae^{i\bar{k}.\bar{r}},E_{y}=Be^{i\bar{k}.\bar{r}},E_{z}=Ce^{i\bar{k}.\bar{r}}$ (same $k$ in all of them), if we call $\bar{E}_{0}=A\hat{x}+B\hat{y}+C\hat{z}$ and we apply $\nabla . \bar{E}=0$, we get $i\bar{k}\cdot \bar{E}_{0}=0$, which then requires that the field and propagation vector are orthogonal (i.e. we reach this conclusion, instead of assuming it from the beginning, when we solve for general plane wave solution).  Thus we've first to prove that $k$ is same in all components

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "comes afterwards". the example you use assume the same propagation vector, for which the polatization plane then needs to lie in the perpendicular plane. But that does not mean the propagation needs to be the same.

Answer (score -1):

For a superposition of solutions, $k_0,\vec{k}$ need not be the same for different components of $\vec{E}$.

Comment: @anonymous minus guy: If you think this is not the correct answer, be bold and improve it. Otherwise, move on.